# ECS/EC2 ASG not scaling out for new service tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, autoscaling

I'm relatively new to ECS, for the most part its been fine, but lately I'm facing an issue that I can seem to find an intuitive solution for.

I'm running a ECS cluster with an EC2 capacity provider. EC2 has an AutoScalingGroup with a `min_capacity: 1` & `max_capacity: 5`.

Each ECS service task has auto scaling enabled based upon CPU/Memory utilisation.

The issue I'm seeing is that when new Tasks and being deployed as part of our CI/CD, ECS returns `unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirementsunable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements`.

I'm wondering how I get ECS to trigger a scale out event for the ASG when this happens? Do I need a particular scaling policy for the ASG? (I feel its related to this)

I attempted to setup a EventBridge/Cloudwatch alarm to trigger a scale out event whenever this happens but seems hacky. It worked, not ideally but worked. Surely there is a nicer/simpler way of doing this?

Any advice or points from experience would be greatly appreciated!

(PS - let me know if you need any more information/screenshots/code examples etc.)

Comment: Do you really need to use EC2? Why not Fargate?

Comment: You need to move to `Capacity Provider Strategy` in your ECS service. You can see this option when you update your service from console just below `Launch Type`.

Comment: @RahulSharma you are a lifesaver, thanks! That was exactly the issue in my case.